# R curve() on expression involving vector

Tags: r, vectorization, curve

I'd like to plot a function of x, where x is applied to a vector. Anyway, easiest to give a trivial example:

```
var <- c(1,2,3)
curve(mean(var)+x)
curve(mean(var+x))
```

While the first one works, the second one gives errors:
'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n' and
In var + x : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Basically I want to find the minimum of such a function: e.g.

```
optimize(function(x) mean(var+x), interval=c(0,1))
```

And then be able to visualise the result. While the optimize function works, I can't figure out how to get the curve() to work as well.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in the general case using `sapply`:

```
curve(sapply(x, function(e) mean(var + e)))
```

In the specific example you give, `mean(var) + x`, is of course arithmetically equivalent to what you're looking for. Similar shortcuts might exist for whatever more complicated function you're working with.

Comment: Yeah, bad example, should have said  `mean(var)^x` or something instead. Thanks though, both yours and Roland's answers are what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

The function needs to be vectorized. That means, if it evaluates a vector it has to return a vector of the same length. If you pass any vector to `mean` the result is always a vector of length 1. Thus, mean is not vectorized. You can use `Vectorize`:

```
f <- Vectorize(function(x) mean(var+x))
curve(f,from=0, to=10)
```